# Give priority to those fields where match was found

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose i have these fields:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+
| id     | read_to  | read_from |
+--------+----------+-----------+
|   1    |    0     | 0         |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Now let's say i make simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
```

Now i would like to select **first** those fields `WHERE read_to = 1 OR read_from = 1`

And then select rest of the data.

So for example if have this kind of structure:

```
1 - 0 - 0
2 - 1 - 0
3 - 0 - 0
4 - 1 - 1
```

I would get something like this:

```
2 - 1 - 0
4 - 1 - 1
1 - 0 - 0
3 - 0 - 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that lets you specify condition for "promoted" records.

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN read_to = 1 AND read_from = 1 THEN 0 -- you can tune the condition here
  ELSE 1
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of questions:

- Are `read_to` and `read_from` always 0 or 1?
- Is there any specific ordering you need?

If the values are always 1 or 0 and you don't need a specific ordering, you could use an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY
    read_to DESC,
    read_from DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use ORDER BY clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY read_to,read_FROM DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1
ORDER BY
  Table1.read_to DESC,
  Table1.read_from ASC
```